# How much it takes memory to download all sdk tools for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin

I am new to android development. I want to download sdk tools for eclipse ide. How much disk space will it take to install all sdk tools? And what are the important tools to download, in case downloading all will take huge amount of time and memory?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi - incorrect, development tool questions are explicitly on topic.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi - again, untrue.  When you look at the actual responses, this comes down to the non-trivial question of what is actually needed.

Comment: There is no need to follow any links.  More importantly though - closing this doesn't serve any benefit, other than to waste time of everyone involved.

Comment: This may be a poor quality question, I agree it is on-topic. Voting to reopen but the OP should expect to edit it or get lots of downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADT bundle (tailored Eclipse with SDK, tools, etc.) comes in a 528 Mb zip file. I think is a good idea to download it complete if you are new to Android (and have space enough), instead of picking pieces of it here and there...

Comment: Thanks, I tried to download everything shown by SDK manager. And about 5 GB of my disk space was covered by it and still it was incomplete so I opted to abort the process.

Comment: @waz - try grabbing fewer emulator varieties and target platforms.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check out the sizes for different files in a version.

See, http://completefaq.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-android-apis-on-myself.html